# How to extract number of rows for every value in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge excel with more than 30 thousands records.
One of the columns is called "Collection" have maybe 1000 different values.
I want to take sample 5 records from each value of the "Collection" field.
Which will end us up with 5 thousands record out from 30 thousands.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert "A" column with sequential numbers to be able to re-order data in same order [Optional]

Insert "B" column with =rand() in each row and sort according to this column to randomize order [Optional]

Insert "C" column with C2 = COUNTIF(D$2$:D2,D2)<=5 and then copy the formula down to all the rows in this column

Assuming "D" is the column containing "Collection" info

Note that only the first cell in the reference cell inside the COUNTIF is made absolute by the $. The other is kept relative and will change when you're copying the formula down. This will make the formula only count the cells above it that have the same value on the "Collection" column. The "<=" operator will output TRUE if there are 5 or less rows that have the same value in the "D" column but only counting cells above. Finally using Auto Filter hide all rows for which the "C" column has a FALSE value. The remaining rows are 5 samples of each unique value in the "Collection" column. Copy or use at your discretion. Cheers.